# How to return null in Listview.builder while condition is false

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

i am using Listview.builder with firebase i want to show available users in firebase but i don't want to show current Logged user in list

```
StreamBuilder(
 stream: firebase.snapshots(),//firebase.snapshots(),
 builder: (context,userdata){
   if(userdata.hasData){
     return Expanded(
       flex: 1,
       child: Container(
         child: ListView.builder(
             itemCount: userdata.data!.docs.length,
             itemBuilder: (context,index){
               if(userdata.data!.docs[index].id != currentUser!.uid)
                 {
                   return UserItem(
                     deviceSize: deviceSize,
                     username:   userdata.data!.docs[index]['username'],
                     imageUrl: userdata.data!.docs[index]['imageUrl'],
                   );
                 }
               else{
                 return Container();
               }
             
             }),
       ),
     );
   }else{
     return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 112, 62, 254),),);
   }
}
  )
```

Comment: please elaborate your question and add firebase JSON to understand batter .

Comment: Add your code of firebase.snapshots()

Comment: Edit your question and add code of stream's method

Comment: Also, don't do this `stream: firebase.snapshots(),` Assign your stream to a Stream variable in initState and then use the variable  name in the stream. Otherwise you will be reading from the database waaaay more than you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a List with condition in builder itself before jumping to Listview directly.

```
StreamBuilder(
 stream: firebase.snapshots(),
 builder: (context,userdata) {
   if(userdata.hasData) {
     if(userdata.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
       return Center(
        child: Text('No data found.')
     );
    } else {
        List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<dynamic>> available_users = userdata.data!.docs
                                        .where((QueryDocumentSnapshot<dynamic> element) =>
                                            element.id != currentUser!.uid)
                                        .toList();
      if(available_users.isNotEmpty) {
      return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: available_users.length,
               itemBuilder: (context,index){
                     return UserItem(
                       deviceSize: deviceSize,
                       username:   available_users[index]['username'],
                       imageUrl: available_users[index]['imageUrl'],
                     );             
               }
        );
      } else {
        return Center(
                    child: Text('No data found.')
            );
        }
   }

   } else {
     return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 112, 62, 254),),);
        }
    }
)
```